# Symfony pagination error here are no registered paths for namespace "KnpPaginator"

Tags: symfony, pagination, knppaginator

I'm using knp-paginator and I have a controller

```
public function offers(Request $request)
{
    $locations= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Oobject::class)->findAll();

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    dump(get_class($paginator));
    $result = $paginator->paginate(
        $locations,
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
        $request->query->getInt('limit', 3)
    );

    return $this->render('main/offers.html.twig', array
        ('controller_name' => 'MainController',
        'locations' =>$result)
    );
}
```

Everything works as expected until I add pagination into html.twig file like so:

```
<div>
    {{knp_pagination_render(locations)}}
</div>
```

I get an error "There are no registered paths for namespace "KnpPaginator"."
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I will assume you've everything setup as explained in [docs](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) if so can you show that in the OP? Also does `$locations` has values?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by adding this path in `twig.yaml` file:

```
paths:
    '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle/templates':KnpPaginator
```

Answer (score 0):

in twig.yaml file add:

```
twig:
    paths: 
       '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle/templates': KnpPaginator
```